# Executing a remote application from server to client machine C#

Tags: c#

My motive is to to execute a program (e.g. winword which is installed on a server) at a client machine. And also the end user should not know the program is running form a remote machine i.e. end user just click on a button and the program get executed without asking any credentials.

Please help me how can i achieve this target.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See http://csharp.net-informations.com/remoting/run-remote-application.htm

I hope it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run the application over Remote Desktop using Seamless Windows, called RemoteApp on Windows Server 2008.

As a starting point, check out this article: [Terminal Services RemoteApp (TS RemoteApp)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844%28WS.10%29.aspx)